# How do I limit packet capturing in Wireshark to only a specific protocol?

Tags: wireshark, protocol, ports, network-protocols, sniffing

I would like to listen to HTTP traffic on port 8080. When I start capturing packets in Wireshark, it's flooded by packets using the SSDP protocol on port 1900. I would like to limit the packet capturing to only HTTP or maybe only HTTP on port 8080. How can I do this in Wireshark?

On `File > Preferences...` and under `Protocols` I have removed the 1900 port from HTTP and 8080 is already there.

I have typed `http` in the "Filter" textfield, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the filter field enter `tcp.port eq 8080`

*Ref.:* Wireshark: Help -> Manual pages -" Wireshark Filter ...

As far as I know this is an alternate HTTP port in TCP only:

> HTTP alternate (http_alt)—commonly used for Web proxy and caching
>   server, or for running a Web server as a non-root user and Apache
>   Tomcat in TCP only

*Ref.:* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Hope this help. Let us know.  :)

Comment: This tells me it's not a valid capture filter, and i should use a display filter - any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a capture filter to filter out the udp packets:
not udp port 1900
You can find more information about capture filters in the [Wireshark User's Guide](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCaptureFilterSection.html) or the [Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters).

Comment: This returns a syntax error message.

Comment: Did you use it a a display filter?
This is a capture filter (not a display filter). You have to add it before you start capturing:
Wireshark
Capture | Options
Add the capture and hit start.

If you want to use [Tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) to capture packets:
$ tshark -i 4 -f "not udp port 1900" -w not_udp.pcap

Answer (score 1):

```
tcp.port == 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a display filter to filter out the udp packets:

not udp.port == 1900
!(udp.port == 1900)

You can find more information about display filters in the [Wireshark User's Guide](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkDefineFilterSection.html) or the [Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters).

Comment: You can edit your other answer instead of posting another one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in traffic on tcp/8080, a capture filter would be better choice.

capture filter: tcp port 8080

This will filter as the traffic is coming in vs loading all the traffic in wireshark and using a display filter to trim down the results.